# What wiring diagram symbol is shown in this image?

Tags: alternator, shield

What wiring diagram symbol is shown in this image?

This is from my automotive electrical class.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide some context. Is there anything around it? What other symbols are in the question? What country? A particular car make? Note that if you post the work of someone else you need to give credit (book title or web link).

Comment: This is such a niche symbol that I doubt the question is even on-topic here. https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/ might be a better site for it.

Comment: Maybe you'll find it in ISO 7000 https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:pub:PUB400001:en

Comment: It's not much of a "class" if you have no way to learn this in class, or by asking the instructor, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The symbol is of an automotive generator. I've found it in [this Car Gurus forum post about the Mercedes S500 electrical diagram](https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/Discussion-t19866_ds859344).

The question shows a cropped symbol without the context needed for use and interpretation.

In use, there would be circuits (lines/wires) connecting to the thing. From what I've seen so far, both (1) and (2) would be the same output circuit, but on separate terminals to accommodate electrical harnessing needs.

[image]

<sub>Drawing by the answerer</sub>

There's no such symbol in the ISO 7000 symbol set.